# Не принимается почта серверами gmail с моего домена

Tags: gmail, ispmanager, exim

Имеется сервак с панелькой ISPmanager Lite 5.86.1. В панельке настроен домен avto13.kz, создан почтовый ящик support@avto13.kz. Для этого домена используются локальные сервера, для остальных доменов используются сервера яндекса для отправки почты. При отправке писем на сервера gmail возвращается вот такое письмо

```
scarfase1989@gmail.com
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.205.27]:
    550-5.7.1 [89.218.155.38] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to
    550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your
    550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at
    550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError h27si355463ljb.60 - gsmtp

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <support@avto13.kz>
Received: from [внешний_айпи_офиса] (helo=[192.168.2.126])
    by ct38.splus.kz with esmtpa (Exim 4.84_2)
    (envelope-from <support@avto13.kz>)
    id 1cnzrx-0008HM-1C
    for scarfase1989@gmail.com; Wed, 15 Mar 2017 09:45:01 +0600
```

Что можно сделать? Я грешу на ptr записть айпи 89.218.155.38. Она возвращает имя static-155-38.splus.kz, а имя сервера ct38.splus.kz. Возможно ли в этом проблема?

Comment: Получается что ваше письмо GMail получает с домена ct38.splus.kz а не avto13.kz, поэтому и говорит что вы не можете отправлять с avto13.kz так как по сути сидите на другом домене, а это нельзя так как написано тут (https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError) Чтобы отправлять с ВАШЕГО домена почтовый сервер должен быть настроен на НЕМ, а не на ct38.splus.kz, или же на ct38.splus.kz должен быть настроен перенаправитель (relay) как и написано у Google в этой ссылке.

Comment: @scarfase, gmail посылает вас сюда https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10336 И посмотрите ваш адрес в black lists https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a89.218.155.38&run=toolpage

Comment: почтовый сервер должен быть настроен на НЕМ, а не на ct38.splus.kz, на нем настроенна панель управления ISPmanager Lite 5.86.1, соответственно конфиги там не мои. Я думаю что там предусмотрены варианты отправки писем  с разных доменов, это же панель управления. Пару строк из конфигов exim >
domainlist relay_to_domains = lsearch;/etc/exim/domains 
строка из файла /etc/exim/domains >
avto13.kz:avto13.kz::no
строка из файла /etc/exim/domainips>
avto13.kz:89.218.155.38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том что ip сервера попал в спам лист. После удаления из спам листа почта стала исправно приходить.
[Вставить свой айпи для проверки](https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/)